# <any> in an XSD does not work?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to create an xml-schema (xsd) to validate an xmlfile.

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>...</c>
        <d>...</d>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c>...</c>
        <e>...</e>
            <d>...</d>
    </b>
<a>
```

1 a-element.
Multiple b-elements, that have some content.

I want to validate that a is present in the file, and 1 or more occurances of b. I'm not interested to know what is inside of b.

So this is what I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="a">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="b" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="b">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any minOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I hoped that the [any](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_complex_any.asp)-element would do the magic trick, but it does not. What am I doing wrong?

**edit:**
XmlSpy gives me this error: Element 'c' not defined in DTD/Schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the additional 'b' in the schema, I think what you're looking for is this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="a">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="b" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This states that you have `<a>` as a root node, and it can contain one or more `<b>`s

**Edit:** Sorry, didn't read the full question - try the above!

**Second edit:** Another attempt above!

Comment: Unfortunately not. XmlSpy gives me this error: Element 'c' not defined in DTD/Schema.

Comment: after edit: still the same error: XmlSpy gives me this error: Element 'c' not defined in DTD/Schema. +1 for effort though.

Answer (score 2):

isn't as free and easy as first appears. By default, I believe, the contents of the element must still conform to the schema, it's just that they can be anything *from* that schema.

If you want to have elements not present in the schema, you need to define it as this:

```
<xs:any minOccurs="1" processContents="lax"/>
```

You can use "skip" rather than "lax", which is even less restrictive.

See the [W3C spec](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/xmlSchema2001Reference/Standard//xmlschema-1.html#Wildcard_details) for more info.

Comment: XmlSpy gives me this error: Element 'c' not defined in DTD/Schema. Both with lax and skip.